# LVM block allocation for snapshots

Tags: lvm

I've found this in 'man 8 lvcreate', which raises some questions for me. So:

> -s, --snapshot OriginalLogicalVolume{Name|Path}
>
> ... Thin snapshot shares same blocks within the thin pool volume. ;

**Question**: *same blocks*? Same blocks as the Origin of the Snapshot, or just "also blocks form the same pool", or ...

---

Side question, as I'm new to LVM: How could I find out, which blocks belong to which file on a LVM system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For unchanged data snapshots use the same blocks as the snapshot origin (that's the principle of copy-on-write snapshots).

If there are several "normal" snapshots then changed data is written to all of them. But several thin snapshots use the same block for data that has been changed once only. If after making the second snapshot the same address is written again then also thin snapshots need two blocks, of course.